# Rails ignoring/overwriting params passed in body of json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Using rails 4.1.4

im sending post request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Cache-Control:no-cache" -H "Postman-Token:872ae843-bc12-8194-5984-ab2534fa9872" -d '{
  "car" : {
    "car_brand" : 1,
    "car_model" : 1,
    "car_version" : 1,
    "name" : "first car"
  }
}' http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/car_groups/1/cars
```

endpoint in my routes:

```
resources :car_groups, only: :none do
  resources :cars, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
end
```

this it what my server sees:
[image]

params passed in url are listed in params as supposed to.

while sending a request with empty body, when i check for params, answer looks the same:

```
> {"action"=>"create", "controller"=>"api/v1/cars", "car_group_id"=>"1", "car"=>{}, "format"=>"json", "auth_token"=>nil}
```

what might i be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was related to versioning apis using mimetype